# Can I "block" a function until an asynch thread has finished?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have this code on WinForm:

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ThreadFunction())
        .ContinueWith(t => ThreadFunctionComplete()
        , CancellationToken.None
        , TaskContinuationOptions.None
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    ThreadFinished();
}
```

and I'd like to start `ThreadFinished()` only when `ThreadFunctionComplete()` has been finished. Well, I could put `ThreadFinished()` at the end of `ThreadFunctionComplete()`, but for some workflow of the process I won't. Is it possible? A sort of wait/lock maybe?

Comment: Why can't you just use `ContinueWith()` again, with `ThreadFinished()` this time?

Comment: Which version of C# are you using?

Comment: Why don't you simply queue it at the end of the Task like you did with `ThreadFunctionComplete`?

Comment: @NicholasButler I think you mean which version of C# and VS and .net (assuming you don't want to use the beta BCL lib) are you using?

Comment: @Aron I was asking if using `async/await` was an option as that would be a neat solution.

Comment: @NicholasButler yeah. I noticed :P. It needs support from Visual Studio 2012, since its C#5 AND also needs the .net 4.5 libs (or the beta BCL libs). I did upvote you...I was just be pedantic :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you can simply call `ContinueWith` twice:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(....)
            .ContinueWith(...)
            .ContinueWith(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wait() but it will block the current thread...

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(...).Wait();
```

Or add another ContinueWith()

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(...).ContinueWith(t => ThreadFinished());
```

Comment: `Wait` will block the UI in this case

Comment: Yes it will. I noted that.